# Permutations of points in the projective plane

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, projective-geometry, automorphism-groups, automorphisms

Let $p_1,...,p_7\in\mathbb{P}^{2}$ be seven general points in the projective plane $\mathbb{P}^{2}$ over the complex numbers.

Let $f$ be an automorphism of $\mathbb{P}^{2}$ inducing a permutation of $\{p_1,...,p_7\}$.

Does this imply that $f$ is the identity on $\mathbb{P}^{2}$ ?

Comment: (out of curiosity) Why seven? What is known about the cases with fewer points?

Answer (score 1):

If you fix a general quadrilateral, you fix the coordinates of every point in the affine chart of that quadrilateral. See Bumcroft, **Modern Projective Geometry**, chapter 3, section I or Hartshorne, [**Foundations of Projective Geometry**](http://www.math.rug.nl/~piter/KR/Hartshorne.pdf). If you permute the order of points in the quadrilateral, you move around which points lie in the affine chart, covering the whole plane.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question quite. You can see that your $f$ generates a finite abelian group, since some power fixes 4 points. So then $f$ generates a finite cyclic subgroup of $PU(3)$, being compact so lying in a maximal compact. One can then diagonalize $f$. I hope this helps.